# Hybris multi-tenant exception

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I want to build a multi-tenant application with different store and database for each slave tenant. I followed the instructions here: https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/Multi-Tenant+Systems , but when I try to open the slave tenant store - ge.telco.local:9001/getelcostorefront - , I have this exception:

Given current tenant is master but returned servlet context related web context (Root WebApplicationContext - /getelcostorefront: startup date [Mon May 04 14:43:24 EEST 2015]; parent: hybris Application context - ge) is attached to other tenant ge

```
tenant_ge.properties:

website.telco.http=ge.telco.local:9001 website.telco.https=ge.telco.local:9002

telcostorefront.webroot=/getelcostorefront storefrontContextRoot=/getelcostorefront
```

How can I call telcostorefront from the slave tenant context?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I Believe Multi-Tenant has been Deprecated in Hybris Version 5.+.

Comment: I think you are referring to the tenant scope, which is indeed deprecated, I'm trying to configure slave tenants, and at hmc and hac level, init, etc, it works, but i'm not able to open separate stores for each tenant.